# print nested loop of arrays with different length

Tags: java, arrays

I'm developing a prototype for a large system, but I came across a problem with getting the values from two different arrays using for loop. The problem occurs because both arrays have different lengths but I need them to run in the same loop. FYI ArrayOne will always have +1 length of ArrayTwo. Can anyone think of a way to get the below code working?

Thank you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < getArrayOne().length; i++) {            
    System.out.print(getArrayOne()[i] + " " + getArrayTwo()[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure `i` is within the bounds of the second array each time before you print it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getArrayOne().length; i++) {        
    System.out.print(getArrayOne()[i] + " ");
    if(i < getArrayTwo().length) { // check that i is within bounds of ArrayTwo
        System.out.print(getArrayTwo()[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Or, since you know that:

> ArrayOne will always have +1 length of ArrayTwo

You could just run the loop you have up to the length of ArrayTwo (the shorter one) and then print the remaining element of ArrayOne

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < getArrayTwo().length; i++) {            
    System.out.print(getArrayOne()[i] + " " + getArrayTwo()[i] + " ");
}
System.out.print(getArrayOne()[i]);
```

Due note that this will break or not work properly if the condition `ArrayOne.length == ArrayTwo.length + 1` isn't true.

Comment: Thank you. I got my head around it now :)